# How to filter a two dimensional array using data from a different one dimensional array - Javascript/Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, filtering

I'm still very novice at app scripts and javascript, but the more I learn, the easier my job gets.

I have a one dimensional array (var shippingID) and a two dimensional array (var shipDetailsArr).  ShippingID acts as a filter for the first column of shipDetailsArr.  I want to return all the columns shipDetailsArr where the first column ONLY equals any of the cells from ShippingID.  How can I do this on the script editor in app scripts?

Here's an example of the two arrays. The first array is a Shipment ID with a few [shipments](http://ibb.co/9vs385R). The 2nd is a larger set of [data](http://ibb.co/CmN2Rsw) that has Shipment ID as the first column. I want to create a new array that returns the 2nd set of data with only the Shipping IDs from the first set. Hope this makes sense, and thanks for your help

Thanks for any suggestions!

Eric

Comment: Ciao Eric, could you provide an example of arrays and what you want to achieve? Would be very appriciated.

Comment: Ciao Giovanni,

Here's an example of the two arrays

The first array is a Shipment ID with a few shipments
https://ibb.co/9vs385R

The 2nd is a larger set of data that has Shipment ID as the first column
https://ibb.co/CmN2Rsw

I want to create a new array that returns the 2nd set of data with only the Shipping IDs from the first set.

Hope this makes sense, and thanks for your help.

Eric

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito  Don't think your answer is invalid. It's more than enough for what OP is asking

Comment: @EricJohnson Provide your current code

Answer (score 3):

Ciao, supposing that you have `shippingID` as an arry of strings and `shipDetailsArr` is a 2D array, with javascript you could use `filter` function in this way:

```js
let shippingID = ["20-05-01-SHEN-EU", "20-05-01-SHEN-CAN"];
        let shipDetailsArr = [["20-05-01-SHEN-EU", "PJ0201", "CE-12-SLOT-WOOD-WATCH-DARK"],
        ["20-05-01-SHEN-CAN", "PJ0201", "CE-12-SLOT-WOOD-WATCH-DARK"], 
        ["20-05-01-SHEN-US", "PJ0201", "CE-12-SLOT-WOOD-WATCH-DARK"]];

        let result = shipDetailsArr.filter(det => shippingID.includes(det[0]));

        console.log(result);
```

As you can see from result, I filtered `shipDetailsArr` using `shippingID.includes(det[0])`. This returns only `shipDetailsArr` with a `shipmentID` present in `shippingID` array.

Comment: While this might be a javascript solution, I don't think it is a valid one. The op specified that he has a filter list from a particular spreadsheet file. Namely, he wants to retrieve this list from there and work with spreadsheet files.

Comment: If you look question tags, I can't find "spreadsheet". But I can see "javascript"...

Comment: google-apps-script is the tag. Spreadsheets are mentioned in his comment.

Comment: But `shipDetailsArr` is a 2D array as written in the post. Snippets  and JavaScript solutions are ok.. but op didn't mention array of json objects. It's just a 2D array. ``[[rowdata],[rowdata]]``... like ``[[a1,b1,c1],[a2,b2,c2]]``

Comment: Ignore the rest in this link, but look into  2Darray structure from spreadsheet https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/reading

Comment: @TheMaster now should be correct :) No problem, your observation is correct

Comment: Still don't think op will accept yours. As all arrays from sheet are 2D: *I have a one dimensional array (var shippingID)* is a  probably wrong, unless He used flat() on the first one. The answer is valid for the question stated. Avoiding answering codeless questions would be better.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution:

Use the following code:

```
function filter2D() {
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  
  const dsh = ss.getSheetByName('All Data');
  const data = dsh.getRange('A1:G20').getValues();
  const fsh = ss.getSheetByName('Filter Data');
  const filterList = fsh.getRange('A2:A13').getValues().flat([1]);
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName('Output Data');
  
  const f_data = data.filter(function (row) {
    return filterList.includes(row[0]);
  }); 
  osh.getRange(1,1,f_data.length,f_data[0].length).setValues(f_data);
}
```

Note that you can modify the ranges for both `Filter Data` and `All Data` according to your needs. I also use a third sheet with the name `Output Data` to store the filtered data.

---

### Other Example:

Here is an example on how you can filter a 2D array based on values of a 1D array:

```
function filter2D() {
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const data = sh.getRange('A1:D18').getValues();
  const filterList = sh.getRange('F1:F2').getValues().flat([1]);
  
  const f_data = data.filter(function (row) {
    return filterList.includes(row[0]);
  }); 
  sh.getRange(24,1,f_data.length,f_data[0].length).setValues(f_data);
}
```

### Explanation:

You will use the [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function to find the rows in the 2D array `data` that meet a particular condition. That is, the first column (`row[0]`) should contain values from `filterList`. In order to check whether this happens you can use [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes). Then, I store the filtered data `f_data` back to the sheet. Of course this is just for illustration. Feel free to adjust this code to your needs.

### Spreadsheet Input and Output:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2):

```
function getDetailsForAnId(id='1') {//default used for testing
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('All Data');
  const vs=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var oA=[];
  oA.push([id].concat(new Array(sh.getLastColumn()-1)));//display id only on first line of each section
  vs.forEach(function(r){
    if(r[0]==id) {
      let t=r.slice();
      t[0]='';//remove unnecessary id in output only for clarity
      oA.push(t);
    }
  });
  if(oA) {
    //console.log(oA);
    return oA;
  };
}

function loopThruIdsAndDisplayOnOutputSheet() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const osh=ss.getSheetByName('OutputSheet');
  osh.clearContents();//clear output sheet when starting
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Filter Data');
  const ids=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
  ids.forEach(function(id){
    let rows=getDetailsForAnId(id);
    if(rows) {
      osh.getRange(osh.getLastRow()+1,1,rows.length,rows[0].length).setValues(rows);
    }
  });
}
```

All Data(csv):

```
COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5,COL6,COL7,COL8,COL9,COL10,COL11,COL12,COL13,COL14,COL15,COL16,COL17,COL18,COL19,COL20,COL21,COL22,COL23,COL24,COL25,COL26
1,0,14,6,0,19,6,24,22,6,4,17,7,15,4,3,16,5,9,8,20,2,9,15,24,12
2,22,15,3,19,22,23,12,9,14,15,7,0,13,8,20,12,20,4,19,18,9,3,3,2,13
3,23,8,20,9,13,19,10,18,24,23,0,17,16,9,9,12,1,24,1,23,6,11,13,3,10
1,11,6,17,0,17,12,12,4,5,6,10,24,22,21,17,11,17,20,18,1,20,7,18,21,9
2,17,12,5,8,24,10,14,13,15,23,21,20,17,9,20,3,16,11,21,23,1,6,23,18,24
3,22,8,24,2,12,22,6,1,5,1,6,2,20,22,1,7,24,23,6,15,19,15,16,19,21
1,3,21,18,24,9,19,3,23,3,10,23,7,14,16,10,7,0,9,14,20,20,15,16,11,11
2,15,13,23,2,11,14,2,6,24,3,16,18,10,10,8,4,1,4,11,7,10,18,17,7,11
3,22,17,19,8,2,13,3,3,21,19,19,3,14,2,11,5,8,22,6,5,1,13,3,4,18
1,13,13,8,22,6,18,14,8,10,1,24,23,12,21,8,19,11,0,4,23,3,22,20,5,5
2,16,16,18,13,9,15,18,12,23,20,17,13,17,8,1,5,5,11,23,12,12,11,21,21,17
3,2,4,17,10,5,18,4,11,7,4,15,1,0,2,11,15,13,20,10,14,22,12,16,12,9
1,12,0,21,2,17,5,1,17,1,12,9,5,9,8,5,18,20,19,14,22,23,11,6,23,7
2,16,2,16,1,9,15,4,20,22,2,19,9,14,10,2,8,6,12,6,15,7,17,21,20,20
3,22,9,16,9,22,10,1,18,16,19,21,13,16,16,18,20,15,5,2,9,16,21,14,7,6
1,20,19,23,18,13,10,13,16,9,23,11,15,20,0,8,18,1,19,2,1,7,7,16,16,11
2,3,12,7,5,6,5,24,19,12,5,20,5,11,10,13,8,1,22,12,16,16,10,8,1,6
3,6,18,18,23,13,22,8,22,4,8,24,2,2,20,13,12,21,12,19,0,1,21,0,24,11
1,15,23,9,1,15,14,5,2,7,0,8,5,6,15,15,10,20,17,9,17,23,17,10,10,11
2,18,22,17,8,9,23,24,0,23,10,10,9,18,10,10,24,16,22,11,11,3,14,9,3,9
3,15,15,17,20,13,12,5,4,21,2,10,10,16,13,19,12,7,2,6,14,13,8,10,16,19
1,12,2,8,11,1,8,24,4,11,19,4,20,20,1,10,22,17,15,7,15,18,24,14,1,21
2,9,9,23,9,11,9,12,15,13,17,14,15,16,13,3,3,15,15,6,2,2,1,18,13,24
3,24,4,23,8,15,1,10,8,7,13,4,19,15,13,23,23,4,20,3,5,11,5,10,7,8
1,3,20,12,4,19,0,20,12,18,1,1,1,10,8,21,18,6,20,15,0,2,4,23,5,22
```

Filter Data(csv):

```
HDR1
1
2
3
```

OutputSheet(csv):

```
1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,0,14,6,0,19,6,24,22,6,4,17,7,15,4,3,16,5,9,8,20,2,9,15,24,12
,11,6,17,0,17,12,12,4,5,6,10,24,22,21,17,11,17,20,18,1,20,7,18,21,9
,3,21,18,24,9,19,3,23,3,10,23,7,14,16,10,7,0,9,14,20,20,15,16,11,11
,13,13,8,22,6,18,14,8,10,1,24,23,12,21,8,19,11,0,4,23,3,22,20,5,5
,12,0,21,2,17,5,1,17,1,12,9,5,9,8,5,18,20,19,14,22,23,11,6,23,7
,20,19,23,18,13,10,13,16,9,23,11,15,20,0,8,18,1,19,2,1,7,7,16,16,11
,15,23,9,1,15,14,5,2,7,0,8,5,6,15,15,10,20,17,9,17,23,17,10,10,11
,12,2,8,11,1,8,24,4,11,19,4,20,20,1,10,22,17,15,7,15,18,24,14,1,21
,3,20,12,4,19,0,20,12,18,1,1,1,10,8,21,18,6,20,15,0,2,4,23,5,22
2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,22,15,3,19,22,23,12,9,14,15,7,0,13,8,20,12,20,4,19,18,9,3,3,2,13
,17,12,5,8,24,10,14,13,15,23,21,20,17,9,20,3,16,11,21,23,1,6,23,18,24
,15,13,23,2,11,14,2,6,24,3,16,18,10,10,8,4,1,4,11,7,10,18,17,7,11
,16,16,18,13,9,15,18,12,23,20,17,13,17,8,1,5,5,11,23,12,12,11,21,21,17
,16,2,16,1,9,15,4,20,22,2,19,9,14,10,2,8,6,12,6,15,7,17,21,20,20
,3,12,7,5,6,5,24,19,12,5,20,5,11,10,13,8,1,22,12,16,16,10,8,1,6
,18,22,17,8,9,23,24,0,23,10,10,9,18,10,10,24,16,22,11,11,3,14,9,3,9
,9,9,23,9,11,9,12,15,13,17,14,15,16,13,3,3,15,15,6,2,2,1,18,13,24
3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,23,8,20,9,13,19,10,18,24,23,0,17,16,9,9,12,1,24,1,23,6,11,13,3,10
,22,8,24,2,12,22,6,1,5,1,6,2,20,22,1,7,24,23,6,15,19,15,16,19,21
,22,17,19,8,2,13,3,3,21,19,19,3,14,2,11,5,8,22,6,5,1,13,3,4,18
,2,4,17,10,5,18,4,11,7,4,15,1,0,2,11,15,13,20,10,14,22,12,16,12,9
,22,9,16,9,22,10,1,18,16,19,21,13,16,16,18,20,15,5,2,9,16,21,14,7,6
,6,18,18,23,13,22,8,22,4,8,24,2,2,20,13,12,21,12,19,0,1,21,0,24,11
,15,15,17,20,13,12,5,4,21,2,10,10,16,13,19,12,7,2,6,14,13,8,10,16,19
,24,4,23,8,15,1,10,8,7,13,4,19,15,13,23,23,4,20,3,5,11,5,10,7,8|
```

OutputSheet Image:

[image]

BTW Your question asks how to filter a 2D array with a 1D array.  You should be aware that they are both 2D Arrays.  A Single Column is still a 2D Array.